# Issue in jar -xvf command

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception

> C:\Users\sunka\Desktop\CS DEPT\fall 2k16\information structures>jar
>   -xvf week2.zip

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: week2.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:307)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

When I am trying to unzip using jar -xvf, I am getting file not found exception. I used the same command in my office, it was working. I made sure that zip file and jar file are present in the directory.

Comment: "that zip file and jar file are present in the directory." which jar file????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you in same directory where you have zip file placed.
Because if JAVA path is set properly and your are giving right zip file name with correct path it works fine.

Comment: Fixed the issue...file was saved as week2.zip.jar :-( thanks for the comments